# Сумма последовательных значений строк dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Имеются данные о хронологической последовательности побед игроков и получении наград:

```
import pandas as pd 
df= pd.DataFrame({'id':['005','005','005','005','005','005','005','006','006','006'], 
                 'action':['win','win','win','rew_1','win','win','rew_2','win','win','rew_3'], 
                 'event_time':['2022-01-29 12:23:59', '2022-01-29 12:26:38',
                                '2022-01-29 16:57:25', '2022-01-29 17:00:38',
                                '2022-01-29 17:03:20', '2022-01-29 17:07:34',
                                '2022-01-29 17:07:57', '2022-01-30 07:35:57',
                                '2022-01-30 07:39:03', '2022-01-30 07:42:42'], 
                 'fact_win':[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]}) 
print (df)

  id action           event_time  fact_win
0  005    win  2022-01-29 12:23:59         1
1  005    win  2022-01-29 12:26:38         1
2  005    win  2022-01-29 16:57:25         1
3  005  rew_1  2022-01-29 17:00:38         0
4  005    win  2022-01-29 17:03:20         1
5  005    win  2022-01-29 17:07:34         1
6  005  rew_2  2022-01-29 17:07:57         0
7  006    win  2022-01-30 07:35:57         1
8  006    win  2022-01-30 07:39:03         1
9  006  rew_3  2022-01-30 07:42:42         0
```

Требуется найти кумулятивную сумму побед перед получением награды (rew_1, rew_2, rew_3) для каждой награды в разрезе каждого id.

Т.е. суммирование должно происходить по колонке fact_win с учетом предыдущих побед.

Ожидается ответ такого вида (колонка cum_sum):

```
   id action           event_time  fact_win  cum_sum
0  005    win  2022-01-29 12:23:59         1        1
1  005    win  2022-01-29 12:26:38         1        2
2  005    win  2022-01-29 16:57:25         1        3
3  005  rew_1  2022-01-29 17:00:38         0        3
4  005    win  2022-01-29 17:03:20         1        1
5  005    win  2022-01-29 17:07:34         1        2
6  005  rew_2  2022-01-29 17:07:57         0        2
7  006    win  2022-01-30 07:35:57         1        1
8  006    win  2022-01-30 07:39:03         1        2
9  006  rew_3  2022-01-30 07:42:42         0        2
```

Попытка получить необходимую колонку через cumsum() пока не увенчалась успехом:

```
df['cum_sum'] = df[['id', 'action', 'fact_win']].groupby(['id', 'action']).cumsum() 

   id action           event_time  fact_win  cum_sum
0  005    win  2022-01-29 12:23:59         1        1
1  005    win  2022-01-29 12:26:38         1        2
2  005    win  2022-01-29 16:57:25         1        3
3  005  rew_1  2022-01-29 17:00:38         0        0
4  005    win  2022-01-29 17:03:20         1        4
5  005    win  2022-01-29 17:07:34         1        5
6  005  rew_2  2022-01-29 17:07:57         0        0
7  006    win  2022-01-30 07:35:57         1        1
8  006    win  2022-01-30 07:39:03         1        2
9  006  rew_3  2022-01-30 07:42:42         0        0
```

Возможно есть другой метод, вплоть до применения циклов???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df["cum_sum"] = \
    (df
     .groupby(["id", df["action"].ne("win").cumsum().shift().bfill()]) 
     ["fact_win"]
     .cumsum())
```

результат:

```
In [158]: df
Out[158]:
    id action           event_time  fact_win  cum_sum
0  005    win  2022-01-29 12:23:59         1        1
1  005    win  2022-01-29 12:26:38         1        2
2  005    win  2022-01-29 16:57:25         1        3
3  005  rew_1  2022-01-29 17:00:38         0        3
4  005    win  2022-01-29 17:03:20         1        1
5  005    win  2022-01-29 17:07:34         1        2
6  005  rew_2  2022-01-29 17:07:57         0        2
7  006    win  2022-01-30 07:35:57         1        1
8  006    win  2022-01-30 07:39:03         1        2
9  006  rew_3  2022-01-30 07:42:42         0        2
```

Comment: Именно то, что нужно! Благодарю